# Deploy a desktop application from a web site

Tags: asp.net, web-services, clickonce, desktop-application, asp.net-web-api2

I have a requirement to install a desktop application written in visual c++ when our customers log in our asp.net web site. The desktop app will be installed once, but will be updated as a newer version is available. What is the best way to do this?
My second question is that is there a way for my asp.net web app to interact with a window service installed on customer computer and direct the window service to control USB devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My work uses software by a company called Citrix. There is some client side software that goes on the client's PC. When setup correctly, we can click a link on our sharepoint site that will trigger the citrix client software to launch a WPF desktop application from a network drive that will run locally on the clients computer (might be in a virtualized space that Citrix creates). This seems to work well, it runs our WPF applications that use windows authentication. This is all I know about it. You can research more if you're interested.

To answer that second question... Your window service would need to expose some kind of service for the client (asp.net web app) to communicate to it with. So ideally I think setting up the windows service to host a WCF service inside it and use something like named pipes or HTTP protocol to communicate with your application. I don't know what kind of USB devices you are trying to control though, that will take research on your part. But if you can control them with a local console application, you should be able to do the same with a windows service.

Good luck. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I have a desktop application and windows service application already installed to customers for many years for our USB devices. However, all databases are located on customer's location. We are trying developed web based applications with centralized databases at our company and need to exploder our options.

Comment: Hosting a web service in the window service is an interesting idea. I wonder if there is a permission issue to access it from a web site.

Comment: Is this an internal enterprise thing where the customer/client is on your local network? Or is it an external customer connected to the internet?

Comment: Intended use is for external customers having access to internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install an app from a web site, best you can do is prompt the user to download the installer. And asp.net (or any website in general) can't interact with the window service on the client. Imagine going to a website which changes your service settings, installs viruses, etc. A website is pretty much limited to changing cookies and local storage on the client, anything else on the client is inaccessable.

Comment: I am thinking that once a user log in the web site, a prompt page is launched to ask the user to install the application. I do not know if there is a way to check the version of my software with user's permission. For the second part, I am thinking that once a user login, the desktop app also connects to my web service or asp.net web API service. Asp.net web app writes instructions to my web service and desktop app executes the instructions.

Comment: Prompt page is fine but the user will have to download the installer and run it, you can't run it for them. And no, as I said you can't access the file system or registry or anything on the client to check installed software's version.

Comment: There is another way that I can keep tracking customer's app version. My desktop application can send the version info to my server. That is probably I have to do.

Comment: I think your application will need to call the server api to get the latest version number and if that is greater than application's current version then ask the user to upgrade.

Comment: I have not used Microsoft clickonce deployment before as I am mainly using install shield for packaging and installation. It seems that there is a great promise to upgrade software, especially for c# application using clickonce. I will explore that, too.